# How to get the OCSP url from the server certificate in java?

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate

I need some java implementation to read the incoming server certificate. From that I need to get the OCSP url to check for revocation.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Extension.html#getExtensionValue%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356072/how-to-access-certificate-extension-information-values

Comment: Thanks, but which OID is for OCSP ? The above links didn't help.

Comment: Check out the answer on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043376/java-x509-certificate-parsing-and-validating

Answer (score 0):

I had to include bouncy castle provider jar in order to make this work.

One more related query:

Say the product is divided into two repository. Accurev and GIT. We are using bouncycastle library in GIT platform code. The platform runs on Android.

But my application runs in accurev code. Thats the reason, I had to include the bouncy castle jar into my application java project. But I don't want to do this.

Q. I want to access the bouncy castle class files which runs in GIT from Accurev application code. Is this feasible ?