# How to get the Policy Identifier and the Subject Type of Basic Constraints in a X509Certificate of java

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a X509Certificate in java and I want to get the value of the **`Policy Identifier`** which there exists in the **`Certificate Policies`** field, as depicted in the following picture:

[image]

Also, I want to get the value of the **`Subject Type`** in **`Basic Constraints`** field, as depicted in the following picture:

[image]

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\myCert.crt"));
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(in);
    int length = cert.getCertificateExtensionOIDs().size();
    String oid;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        oid = cert.getCertificateExtensionOIDs().iterator().next();
        byte[] UID = cert.getExtensionValue(oid);
        DERObject derObject = toDERObject(UID);
        if(derObject instanceof DEROctetString){
            DEROctetString derOctetString = (DEROctetString) derObject;
            derObject = toDERObject(derOctetString.getOctets());
        }
// here I think, I should use derObject to retrieve cert info but I don't know how!?
}
public static DERObject toDERObject(byte[] data) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        ASN1InputStream DIS = new ASN1InputStream(inStream);
        return DIS.readObject();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at that code. A little more data validation code may be needed and you have to be careful checking basic constraints, because the condition below may not be enough in some cases.

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEROctetString;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.CertificatePolicies;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyInformation;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * 2016 krzysiek
 */
public class App {
    private static final String CERTIFICATE_POLICY_OID = "2.5.29.32";

    private static final String FILENAME = "/test.cer";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            X509Certificate cert = loadCertificate();
            String policyIdentifier = getCertificatePolicyId(cert, 0, 0);

            System.out.println("Policy Identifier: " + policyIdentifier);

            String subjectType = getSubjectType(cert);
            System.out.println("Subject Type: " + subjectType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem with certificate: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String getSubjectType(X509Certificate cert) {
        int pathLen = cert.getBasicConstraints();
        if (pathLen == -1) {
            if (cert.getKeyUsage()[5] || cert.getKeyUsage()[6]) { //simple check, there my be needed more key usage and extended key usage verification
                return "Service";
            } else {
                return "EndEntity";
            }

        } else {
            try {
                cert.verify(cert.getPublicKey());
                return "RootCA";
            } catch (SignatureException | InvalidKeyException e) {
                return "SubCA";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private static X509Certificate loadCertificate() {
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(App.class.getResource(FILENAME).getFile())) {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate certificate = cf.generateCertificate(in);
            X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certificate;

            return cert;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static String getCertificatePolicyId(X509Certificate cert, int certificatePolicyPos, int policyIdentifierPos)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] extPolicyBytes = cert.getExtensionValue(CERTIFICATE_POLICY_OID);
        if (extPolicyBytes == null) {
            return null;
        }

        DEROctetString oct = (DEROctetString) (new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(extPolicyBytes)).readObject());
        ASN1Sequence seq = (ASN1Sequence) new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(oct.getOctets())).readObject();

        if (seq.size() <= (certificatePolicyPos)) {
            return null;
        }

        CertificatePolicies certificatePolicies = new CertificatePolicies(PolicyInformation.getInstance(seq.getObjectAt(certificatePolicyPos)));
        if (certificatePolicies.getPolicyInformation().length <= policyIdentifierPos) {
            return null;
        }

        PolicyInformation[] policyInformation = certificatePolicies.getPolicyInformation();
        return policyInformation[policyIdentifierPos].getPolicyIdentifier().getId();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <bouncycastle.version>1.54</bouncycastle.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>${bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you @Krzysiek , but the line of  `  CertificatePolicies certificatePolicies = new CertificatePolicies(PolicyInformation.getInstance(seq.getObjectAt(certificatePolicyPos))); ` has this error: `cannot resolve constructor CertiicatePolicies`, Also, next line : `certificatePolicies.getPolicyInformation()`  has this error: cannot resolve method getPolicyInformation()

Comment: @H.Aqjn Which Version of BouncyCastle are you using? I've compiled that code with 1.54:

Comment: I am using `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46`

Comment: Your solution completely solve my problem except that it has a conflict with a part of my code which I get crls from crlDistributionPoints. I am using this code: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjWqOm9ir7QAhUItRoKHVTtD0sQFggfMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsvn.apache.org%2Frepos%2Fasf%2Fcxf%2Ftags%2Fcxf-2.4.4%2Fdistribution%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Frelease%2Fsamples%2Fsts_issue_operation%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fdemo%2Fsts%2Fprovider%2Fcert%2FCRLVerifier.java&usg=AFQjCNFBrknjgvu3Hszh_KlfTFRQeaFgNw&sig2=vOWx-7iCVQbdhxSqqUfOHg&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d2s&cad=rja

Comment: Why your solution is not compatible with the last version of bouncyCastle? I think some methods of your approach may be deprecated. Could you please provide a good code (last version of BC) to get the list of getCrlDistributionPoints and solve this question both together?

Comment: @H.Aqjn: This was tested on newest version than yours. Just have a look: bcprov-jdk16:1.46 was released 2011-02-23, but bcprov-jdk15:1.54 which I used was released 2015-12-30 (http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html). You definitely should update your dependencies to e.g version, which I used.

Comment: Dear @Krzysiek your solution has a bit problem: if the certificate has not any `Basic Constraints` your code returns `End Entity`! While it should throw exception that there is not any `Basic Constraints`. Note: subject type exists inside Basic Constraints. How Can I fix it?